# How are pending patents sold / assigned?

Tags: patents

An inventor has filed a utility patent. It is now in pending status.

If a large cooperation really believes in this invention and buys it in its pending state, what happens if for some reason the patent is rejected?

Is this merely a risk that the cooperation has to assume?

Answer (score 2):

### The contract should allocate the risk

That’s what contracts are for.